# Using Angular model as function parameter

Tags: angularjs

In this code below, i like to be able to make the length of my menu dynamic with Angular data binding by taping it in the input and getting it in real time.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<p>Number of characters : <input type="number" ng-model="nmba" ></p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in chars track by $index">
            {{ x}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {

function printCharacters(param) {
   var result = [];
   for (i = 1; i <= param; i++) {
   result.push('a');
}
return result;
}
 $scope.chars = printCharacters($scope.nmba);
 });
</script>
```

So i wrote it as above but it is not displaying anything. Am i missing something ?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Seems working for me [here] (I only updating chars on change of input)(http://plnkr.co/edit/lS9NHKGa5INpOzhhFAWw?p=preview), but don't understood your logic..

Comment: Thank you @Pankaj, you saved me, i was missing the onChange(), thank you

Comment: glad to know that.. thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is becuse `printCharacters` called just on controller init and at this point `$scope.nmba =""`

You need to call this func on any change in input field.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="nmba" ng-change="printCharacters(nmba)">
```

Also you need to expose `printCharacters` to $scope

```
$scope.printCharacters = function(nbma){}
```

Comment: Thank you @Elhay, yes i was missing th 'ng-change- as Pankaj suggested.